# How to prevent label overflow onto multiple lines w/ Bootstrap in FF

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `panel` and `panel-body` within which lies a dynamic number of span elements. In Safari and Chrome, they look fine and move to the next line when they fill up a row. In FF, they do a weird spill over. Please refer to the images:

Chrome, Safari:
[image]

FF:
[image]

The spans are created in an ejs template as part of a Node app. Is this a FF quirk or my error? If the prior, is there a workaround?

```
    <div id="stops">
        <h4>Explore Individual Stops</h4>
        <% for (var d = 0; d < route.stops.length; d++) { %>
            <ul style="float:left">
                <h5><%= route.directions[d] %> Direction</h5>
                <% for (var i = 0; i < route.stops[d].length; i++) { %>
                    <li style="list-style-type:none">
                        <a href="/routes/<%= route.route_id %>/<%= d %>/<%= route.stops[d][i].stop_id %>"><%= route.stops[d][i].stop_name %></a>
                    </li>
                <% } %>
            </ul>
        <% } %>
    </div>
```

Here is an example of one span, once rendered:

```
    <span class="label bus-lapel" 
                id = "BX16"
                style="background-color: #00AEEF;
                            color: #FFFFFF;" 
                onclick="gotoroute('BX16')"
                api-route-boro="Bronx" 
                api-route-desc="via E 233rd St / Nereid Av" 
                api-agency-id="MTA NYCT" 
                api-route-url="http://web.mta.info/nyct/bus/schedule/bronx/bx016cur.pdf">
        Bx16
    </span>
```

Comment: What is above code? can you post a single box html?

Comment: @yjs I edited original question with one, as an example.

Comment: Can you use <div instead of <span with same display:inline-block; property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say for sure since you haven't posted your CSS, but I suspect the problem is that you're styling them as `inline-block` and the problem is due to extra spaces within the `<span>` elements. Instead of

```
<span ...>
    Bx16
</span>
```

You could try either

```
<span ...>Bx16</span>
```

or

```
   <span ...><!--
    -->Bx16<!--
--></span>
```

Comment: Thanks will try this out tonight - css is standard Bootstrap 3, no modification.